# How do you list all the web sites (not applications) being hosted by an IIS server?

Tags: c#, iis

I'm using IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003.  The vision is to create a directory of those applications, showing their urls (ports on Server) and names.

Comment: The client application that will fetch the list from IIS is on the same server where IIS is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done it, but I believe you need to use the following WMI object:

```
DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("IIS://{0}/w3svc", serverName));
foreach (DirectoryEntry site in w3svc.Children)
{
     //these are the web sites, lookup their properties to see how to extract url
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# example: [link text](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2007/06/20/createdeleteview-virtual-directory-or-website-in-iis-using-c/)

or

This is a VB example, but I think you will use this idea:
[link text](http://www.cruto.com/resources/vbscript/vbscript-examples/iis/iis6/web/List-Virtual-Directories.asp)

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject _
("winmgmts:{authenticationLevel=pktPrivacy}\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\microsoftiisv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from IIsWebVirtualDir")
For Each objItem in colItems
  Wscript.Echo "Application Isolated: " & objItem.AppIsolated
  Wscript.Echo "Application Package ID: " & objItem.AppPackageID
  Wscript.Echo "Application Package Name: " & objItem.AppPackageName
  Wscript.Echo "Application Root: " & objItem.AppRoot
  Wscript.Echo "Installation Date: " & objItem.InstallDate
  Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
Next
```

Comment: That script lists Vdirs, not Web sites.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above solutions, assuming if your application is not running on the same server machine where the IIS is, in that case you will need to write a TCPClient to perform **[Reverse DNS](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&q=reverse+dns&rlz=1R2GZAZ_en-GBIN331&aq=f&oq=)** on the IP of the IIS server.

By defination Reverse DNS means:

> In computer networking, reverse DNS
>   lookup or reverse DNS resolution
>   (rDNS) is the determination of a
>   domain name that is associated with a
>   given IP address using the Domain Name
>   System (DNS) of the Internet.